# Mass of H2 in a balloon

Tags: gas-laws, stoichiometry

#### Question

> A balloon of diameter $\pu{2 m}$ has a volume of $\pu{4190 dm^3}.$
>   It floats since it is given an up thrust equal to the mass of air it displaces.
>
> (Given: average $M_\mathrm{r}$ of air = 29.
>   Under conditions of inflation, $\pu{1 mol}$ of $\ce{H2}$ occupies a volume of $\pu{23 dm^3}).$
>
> Find mass of $\ce{H2}$ in balloon.

#### My method

$$\text{Amount of}~\ce{H2} = \frac{\pu{4190 dm^3}}{\pu{23 dm3 mol-1}} = \pu{182.2 mol}$$
$$\text{Mass of}~\ce{H2}~\text{in balloon} = \pu{182.2 mol} × \pu{2 g mol-1} = \pu{364.4 g}$$

Correct answer: $\pu{182.2 g}$.

I don't understand why the answer is 182.2g

Comment: Why are you doubling the mass of H2 in the final step of your calculation? Where does the factor (x2) come from?

Comment: Isn't mass = Mr × number of moles?

Comment: Sure, I just didn't want to guess your thoughts from the numbers (because the guess could be wrong). It might help to edit the post and add a short explanation and the units.

Comment: At first glance your solution looks reasonable. I allowed myself to add missing units – please don't drop them and always carry values and units together.

Comment: Thank you for adding the units.That was my bad.

Comment: Help me please.why is the answer 182.2?or is the answer sheet wrong?

Comment: The answer sheet is wrong.